# Pass function with 1 arg as prop to a child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I am trying to pass a `setResponse()` function as a `prop` to a child component. The function takes one argument (the response) from the child component and calls a `handleChange()` function with 3 arguments (the response and 2 args available in parent component).

I am having the issue that my `setResponse` function is passed in but is only defined on first render i.e. when I `console.log()` in child component function shows up correctly on first render but is subsequently undefined. I put code in question below but added more context below in case more context is needed.

Update:  I think I may need to add setResponse as a dependency in the useEffect within FragmentWrapper, however this leads to an infinite loop...

Update 2:  Made a code sandbox for playing around
https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-sunset-00hzl?file=/src/App.js

Update 3:  I think the issue is most likely in the parent component.  The first time FragmentWrapper is rendered it has the right props, so something must be going on in the parent component (state change or other?) which would cause the FragmentWrapper's props to change and trigger a re-render.  Also not sure why whatever is happening is causing setResponse to become undefined...

```js
const DisplayQuestion = ({ answers, question, onChange }) => {
  return React.createElement(question.component, {
    setResponse: answer => {
      handleChange(answer, question.id, answers)  
    }, // answer passed in from child, question.id and answers available in parent
  })
}
```

Something else I tried was below, but this showed the same behavior (only set on first render then undefined).

```js
const DisplayQuestion = ({ answers, question, onChange }) => {
  const setFunc = (answer) => { 
    handleChange(answer, question.id, answers)
  }
  return React.createElement(question.component, {
    setResponse: setFunc,
    }, 
}
```

Context Code

- DisplayQuestion (calls RadioQuestion)

```
const DisplayQuestion = ({ answers, question, onChange }) => {
  const handleChange = (answer, id, answers) => {
    onChange({ ...answers, [id]: answer })
  }

  return React.createElement(question.component, {
    response: answers[question.id] ? answers[question.id] : null,
    setResponse: answer => {
      handleChange(answer, question.id, answers)
    },
    component: RadioQuestion,
    ...question, // these are other (passed in) props 
  })
}
```

- RadioQuestion (calls FragmentWrapper)

```js
export const RadioQuestion = props => (
  <FragmentWrapper component={RadioFragment} {...props} />
)
```

- FragmentWrapper (calls RadioFragment)

```js
const FragmentWrapper = ({
  questionText,
  response,
  setResponse,
  component: Fragment  
}) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(response || '')

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(setResponse) // prints correct 1st render then undefined
    setResponse && setResponse(value)
  }, [value])

  const handleChange = setter => event => {
    event && event.target ? setter(event.target.value) : setter(event)
  }
  
  const fragmentProps = { value, setValue, options, handleChange }  
  return (
    <>
      <Typography>{questionText}</Typography>
      <Fragment {...fragmentProps} /> 
      // Fragment=RadioQuestion as specified in DisplayQuestion
    </>
  )
}
```

- RadioFragment

```js
export const RadioFragment = ({
  value,
  setValue,
  options,
  handleChange,
}) => {
  return (
    <FormControl>
      <RadioGroup value={value} onChange={handleChange(setValue)} >
        {options.map(option => (
          <FormControlLabel value={option} control={<Radio />} />
        ))}
      </RadioGroup>
    </FormControl>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for adding that last bit, it was starting to get confusing...now let's see if we can figure out the issue at hand

Comment: Within the FragmentWrapper UseEffect I think I may need to add setResponse as a dependency (to update when setResponse changes), but this causes me a maximum update depth exceeded error.  Created a code sandbox if that helps for playing around
https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-sunset-00hzl?file=/src/App.js

Comment: So have you resolved the issue?

Comment: No, it is still undefined after first render + being constantly redefined (as undefined)...  Working on it though, but any insights appreciated!